# Liquibase move table from postgres database to another

Tags: java, postgresql, liquibase

I am trying to move a table from a Postgres database to another using Liquibase Java API. I have tried to generate the changelog between the source DB and the target DB using this code

```xml
Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase(liquibaseOutFile.getAbsolutePath(), new FileSystemResourceAccessor(), database);         liquibase.generateChangeLog(CatalogAndSchema.DEFAULT, changeLogWriter, new PrintStream(liquibaseOutFile.getAbsolutePath()));
Liquibase targetLiquibase = new Liquibase(liquibaseOutFile.getAbsolutePath(), new FileSystemResourceAccessor(), targetDatabase);         
Contexts context = new Contexts();         
targetLiquibase.update(context);
```

It works and it creates only the table schema without the data. What I need is a way to set diffTypes=data with java and include only the designated table.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? If so, can you share?

Comment: no, the one solution was to use a Liquibase script